# Zurb Foundation Off-Canvas and Visibility

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

I am working on a site using Zurb Foundation. The content will be rendered differently based on the size of the screen. If the content is being viewed on a phone, the navigation structure will use a off-canvas nav item for example. To demonstrate, here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LFUvM/5/): http://jsfiddle.net/LFUvM/5/.

In my example, you can see that there is

```
Content Goes Here
```

My problem is, I don't want to write the actual content three times in my HTML. Some of my content is quite large. Is there a way to a) share the content across all three views b) still use the off-canvas nav option?

THank you!

Comment: Is it possible for you to restructure the HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's possible to restructure the HTML a bit you can achieve this with the following setup:

```
<div class="off-canvas-wrap show-for-small-only">
    <div class="inner-wrap">
      <nav class="tab-bar show-for-small-only">
        <section class="tab-bar-section">
          <h1 class="title">Foundation</h1>
        </section>

        <section class="right-small">
          <a class="right-off-canvas-toggle menu-icon"><span></span></a>
        </section>
      </nav>
      <aside class="right-off-canvas-menu">
        <ul class="off-canvas-list">
          <li><label>Users</label></li>
          <li><a href="#">Hari Seldon</a></li>
        </ul>
      </aside>

      <a class="exit-off-canvas"></a>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <h1 class="show-for-small-only">Phone</h1>
    <h1 class="show-for-medium-only">Medium</h1>
    <h1 class="show-for-large-only">Large</h1>
    Content Goes here
</div>
```

And here's the working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brettdewoody/wexHT/).

Answer (score 1):

I made an example using `<section role="main"></section>` after `<a class="exit-off-canvas" href="#"></a>`

You can take a look at it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/3cc3T/2/)

Comment: Thank you for trying this. However, I'm trying to use content that is outside of <div class="off-canvas-wrap">.